# OLS Forecasting Intervals

Tags: forecasting, least-squares, econometrics, prediction-interval

currently studying for my econometrics exam and struggling to understand the difference between these two forecasting intervals. xf are new observations added to the sample.

Could someone please explain to me how the two intervals differ?
What exactly does each interval try to forecast?
And where does the 1+ in the formula of the second one come from?

Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could someone please explain to me how the two intervals differ? What exactly does each interval try to forecast?

The former is a confidence interval.  This represents uncertainty in the conditional mean.  The latter is a prediction interval.  It combines uncertainty in the conditional mean *and* the noise in the data ,$\sigma_\epsilon$.

> And where does the 1+ in the formula of the second one come from?

The expression $\sigma^2_\epsilon (X'X)^{-1}$ is the estimated covariance matrix for the coefficients (assuming $\sigma_\epsilon$ is an estimate of the residual standard deviation).  Hence $x_f \sigma^2_\epsilon (X'X)^{-1} x_f'$ is an estimate of the sampling variance of the conditional mean.  The total uncertainty for a new observation comes from the uncertainty in the conditional mean $x_f \sigma^2_\epsilon (X'X)^{-1} x_f'$ and the uncertainty in future observations assuming we knew the mean exactly, $\sigma^2_\epsilon$.  Hence, the total uncertainty is

$$ \sigma^2_\epsilon + x_f \sigma^2_\epsilon (X'X)^{-1} x_f'$$

$$ =   \sigma^2_\epsilon( 1 + x_f  (X'X)^{-1} x_f')$$

Take the square root of this, and you get the sampling standard deviation, which is the quantity in the prediction interval

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do I understand you correctly that the first part of the variance is due to the beta used to predict the Y of the new observations (Yf) being only based on the old observations in the sample and thus varying around the true beta of the entire sample (so the one also considering the new observations)? And then the second part of the overall variance stemming from Y being forecasted as Y_hat_f with the difference being the normal error term, with the two sources of variance adding up in the end?

Comment: That is correct.  The betas have sampling variability (get a new sample, get slightly different beta) so the first interval tries to convey that uncertainty.  The second interval incorporates the sampling variability in the betas but also adds noise from the observation process.  If we knew the beta's exactly then the only source of variation would be the observation noise.